# Function which cut string and return integer

Tags: string, function, date, substr

I need function whitch from data (always yyyy-mm-dd for example 2010-01-01) cut only month and return me integer not string. But if this month is for example January and first number is 0 function should cut this 0 and return me only 1. I try to do this wuth substr but i always have null. For example from 2014-02-03 fnction return 2. Anyone can help me?
I try to use

```
date('m', strtotime('$myDate'))
```

Its work with years but it useless for me becosue it return me first 01, 02 or example but i need need this withot this 0 becouse i transfer this to array where i have 12 numbers without 0.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Have you tried searching on net for date parsing in that language?

Comment: i using php i think it not good ide with parse

Answer (score 0):

See this exemple with JAVA :

```
public Integer getMonth(String date) {
    date = date.substring(5,7);
    if(date.charAt(1) == 0) {
        date.substring(1);
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(date);
}
```

The function return 2 for date = "2016-02-10"

This is the same for PHP.

This exemple with PHP :

```
<?php

public function getMonth($date) {
$date = substr($date, 5, 2);
if(date[0] == 0) {
    $date = substr($date,1)
} 
return $date;
}

?>
```

I can't try this because I don't have apache in my computer because I work with JAva and ASP.Net.

Comment: hmm can u write this in php pls?

Comment: I've edited my answer if you have a problem with this comment.

Comment: What date = substr(date, 5, 2); return ?

Comment: `code public function getActuallyMonth()
  {
    $date = substr('2016-02-10',5,2);
    if(substr($date,0) == 0) {
    $date2 = substr($date,1);
    return $date2;
    
    }
     return $date;
  } code` this return me 02

Comment: My bad I've forget the "$" , I am a regular java. I've edited with the $ try it.

Comment: i use $data everywhere ;) without that i cant var_dump this and cant check  so i add $ to all variables

Comment: I've changed the substr with a array of char try it :). I don't have Apache/Php for test it...